# Calculate total of total column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 and VS 2008.I am having a query as shown below

```
SELECT  Month
    , SUM(Man) AS Man
    , SUM(Sal) AS Sal
    , SUM(Man + Sal) AS Total
FROM    (        
      SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DOB) AS Month
              , CASE WHEN TypeOfPost = 'Manager' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Man
              , CASE WHEN TypeOfPost = 'Sales' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Sal
      FROM    tableName
    ) g          
GROUP BY
    Month
```

which generates the following output

```
Output--
-------------------------------------
Month      Man      Sal        Total
--------   -----   ------     ---------
January       1       1          2
June          1      NULL        1
November      1       1          2
```

But now I want to calculate the total of Total column.So help me out.

```
Expected Output--
-------------------------------------
Month      Man      Sal        Total
--------   -----   ------     -------
January       1         1         2
June          1        NULL       1
November      1         1         2
-------------------------------------
                      Total       5
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: the "Total" column is not figured in the query !

Comment: sorry FGraviton for that but now have a look i have edited it....

Comment: i think you should use T-SQL to rewrite this query (with variables)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49008514/9331130

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `WITH ROLLUP` option in the `GROUP BY` - this will give you an extra row that contains the "rolled up" (summed up) values:

```
SELECT  Month
    , SUM(Man) AS Man
    , SUM(Sal) AS Sal
    , SUM(Man + Sal) AS Total
FROM    (        
      SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DOB) AS Month
              , CASE WHEN TypeOfPost = 'Manager' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Man
              , CASE WHEN TypeOfPost = 'Sales' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Sal
      FROM    tableName
    ) g          
GROUP BY
    Month WITH ROLLUP
```

The extra line will contain `NULL` for the `Month` column, and should sum up all other columns for you

Comment: `WITH ROLLUP` is not new. Just `GROUPING SETS`. This should work fine in 2005.

Comment: @MartinSmith: sheesh - you're right - this MSDN Books Online is confusing at times.... well - even better! In that case, my solution should work even on 2005, right? :_)

Comment: It's just that, starting from SQL Server 2008, usage of `WITH ROLLUP` and `WITH CUBE` is discouraged in favour of `GROUPING SETS ()`, `ROLLUP ()` and `CUBE ()`. But the clauses are still supported, so, naturally, the query will still work in 2008 versions.

Comment: @marc_s: I have tried both rollup and grouping sets but its not working.

Comment: @StoneCold: **HOW** not working?? Does it give you an error? Does it **NOT** display an extra line??

Comment: Thanks all, I got the solution and is same as that provided by marc_s.