# how to sum values of total column, i.e calculate the sub total? as total is not from database

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2lGY.png)*now how can i calculate the sub total of the (tolal) field values these values are not from database, these are from (price of item * quantity)*

This is my code:

```
 <?php
$ipAdd = getRealIpAddr();

     $checkPrice= "select * from cart where ipAdd= '$ipAdd' ";
     $run= mysqli_query($conn,$checkPrice);
     while($record= mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

     $proId= $record['pId'];
     $cId= $record['cId'];
     $cQuant= $record['qnty'];


     $proPric= "select * from products where prodId= '$proId' ";
     $runPrice=mysqli_query($conn, $proPric);
     while($pPrice=mysqli_fetch_array($runPrice)){

         $proPri= $pPrice['prodPrice'];

         $t = $proPri* $cQuant ;
     }
     }
?>
```

Comment: the while loop is never closed. But you would have noticed that, **if you indented your code correctly**

Comment: it is closed under

Comment: now i closed it there for u @Cashbee

Comment: Why do you have backslahes before your brackets?

Comment: ignore it, it is by stakeoverflow.

Comment: Well, for one, I don't see $total declared anywhere else, is the code not working as it is? You need to give helpful information for anyone to help you

Comment: $t is used now, and assigned the poduct, what is the method of adding these, $total is working,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alrighty, so assuming you want total of all items times all the quantities, here's what you do:

```
$ipAdd = getRealIpAddr();
$total = 0;
$checkPrice = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ipAdd = '$ipAdd' ";
$run = mysqli_query($conn,$checkPrice);
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
    $proId = $record['pId'];
    $cId = $record['cId'];
    $cQuant = $record['qnty'];
    $proPric = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodId = '$proId' ";
    $runPrice = mysqli_query($conn, $proPric);
    $pPrice = mysqli_fetch_array($runPrice);
    $proPri = $pPrice['prodPrice'];
    $t = $proPri * $cQuant ;
    $total += $t;
}
echo $total; // will be a sum of all prices times all quantities
```

- You don't need `while` if you're fetching just one value, literally just removing it works fine
- You start this process by declaring `$total` variable, in this case resetting it
- You do everything you already did, after which you increment `$total` by whatever is the value of `$t`

Keep in mind that `$total` will change during this `while` loop, so considering this looks like a per-user-query, make sure to use it outside of the loop.